# How can I get my Sony a5000 to shoot 2 fps while tethered?

Tags: sony, tethering, sony-nex, burst-mode

Recently, I've been trying to use a Sony ILCE-5000 to take 2 photos per second. The camera trigger is done remotely via USB using a computer, the problem is that on a single shot, the camera takes 2 seconds to process the image.

Then I decided to try Cont. Shooting and Spd Priority Cont modes and both take 2 or more photos for each camera trigger, and then the camera gets blocked for around a second, so I can't get the 2 photos per second. I'm using libgphoto2 in case someone knows how to use it, and can help me.

I would like to know how to limit the photos of the Cont. shooting mode so I don't block the camera, or how to set the parameters to achieve 2 photos per second. Keep in mind that the photos are not saved in the camera sd, but in my computer via USB.

Thanks!

Comment: How long (total time) / how many total photos are you trying to take? Have you tried taking 2 photos per second when using your memory card? If so, how long could it sustain that rate? Did the buffer eventually fill up and cause a pause in the photo rate?

Comment: Reduce the image size: don't shoot Raw, or even choose a lower-quality JPEG.

Comment: @scottbb I'm trying to take +100 photos, between shots usually it takes about half a second, but whenever it feels like it, the camera decides to hang. I can't use the memory card since the images are stored into the RAM and sent via usb to my pc. Whenever I take a shot, I download it and delete it from the camera, so space is freed. About the quality, I'm using the worst one.

Comment: Since this is a question and answer site, please post your update as an answer rather than as an edit to the question itself.

Comment: What is the question? You got a camera that can not do 2 FPS tethered - get another camera. I know it is not what you want to hear, but there is no magic dust you can sprincle ove your camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a problem with the library I was using for tethering (libgphoto2). I posted the bug in their github and they made a patch for all sony cameras. Works fine now.

[More info here](https://github.com/gphoto/libgphoto2/issues/87)